# "Payment address not valid" error on Mycelium

Tags: wallet

I'm trying to deposit BTC into BitBuy, using a Mycelium wallet. When I use Mycelium to scan the QR code, I get a "Payment address is not valid" error. I'm using Mycelium on iPhone, latest iOS. I'm scanning from BitBuy on a PC monitor. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked the address is valid using a blockchain explorer?

Comment: I have the same problem. Anyone?

Comment: What does the address on BitBuy start with? `1…`, `3…`, `bc1q…`, or `bc1p…`?